# Execute task when build is cancelled - Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need my pipeline to run a task if the build is cancelled either by a user or automatically (by the system itself).

Is there any condition to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Would this work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#canceled Not sure if it'll run if system cancels the pipeline though..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `always()`

```
steps:
- script: echo I did a thing
  condition: and(always(), eq(someConditionHere))
```

More on that here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Doesn't that execute the task even if failed or successful? I just want to execute whenever the builds is cancelled

Comment: I guess you can use `always() ` then check first if the build succeeded or it failed with `succeededOrFailed()` then do whatever you want when it is cancelled..

Answer (score 0):

If you need the task to run **only** when the build is canceled, you need to check both `always()` and `succeededOrFailed()`.

Because `succeededOrFailed()` is `false` when the pipeline is canceled, the following condition works:

```
- script: |
    echo "Pipeline was canceled."
  condition: and(always(), eq(succeededOrFailed(), false))
```